# Search in spring mongo multiple collections

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

I have some problem in mongo DB query.
My use case is i want to search in different collections( may be 5) at the same time using a search string. If there any possible way to search using single query can i know plz?
I am trying in springboot.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Different queries per collection?

Comment: Iam trying for single query